# How to run programs compiled from source on other disrtibutions

Tags: compilation, appimage

I have compiled  MusE 4 audio sequencer on my OpenSuse Leap distribution mounted at internal laptop HDD, but during configuration i set the install prefix to be in the directory located at the external HDD partition.

I have installed Linux Mint 21 on a partition of my internal HDD separately from my main OpenSuse distribution. I also installed Ubuntu on a partition of my external HDD separately from the partition containing the compiled MusE program.

Both in Linux Mint and Ubuntu whenever i try to run the compiled executable I receive an error saying that some shared objects (files with .so extension) are missing.

I know there is AppImage, letting you create an independent package container with the program and all of its dependecies and run the program on any system.

But can i create an executable of my program that can be run on whatever system without AppImage, like setting some parameters during compilation so that I can take my external HDD with the compiled program, go to another computer, for example, in the other house/ in the office/ whatever, and run my program there?